# amazon multipart upload PHP sdk version 2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried to **upload large file into Amazon s3 using PHP**. I have found nice solutions on various forums but these solutions are for SDK version 1 .

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LLuploadFilePHP.html

Of course, I have found examples on [Amazon API documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/service-s3.html#uploading-large-files-using-multipart-uploads). This example expects file on local disk and can not **handle with input stream**.

I couldn't find similar examples for the **SDK for PHPv2** as shown in first link.

Did someone solved similar problem successfully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently just prepared a code sample for this. In this example I am using a file, but you can use a stream as well.

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Common\Enum\Size;

// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => '*** your-aws-access-key-id ***',
    'secret' => '*** your-aws-secret-key ***'
));

$file = fopen($filename, 'r');

// 1. Create a new multipart upload and get the upload ID.
$response = $s3->createMultipartUpload(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => $keyname
);
$uploadId = $result['UploadId'];

// 2. Upload the data in parts.
$parts = array();
$partNumber = 1;
while (!feof($file)) {
    $result = $s3->uploadPart(array(
        'Bucket'     => $bucket,
        'Key'        => $key,
        'UploadId'   => $uploadId,
        'PartNumber' => $partNumber,
        'Body'       => fread($file, 5 * Size::MB),
    ));
    $parts[] = array(
        'PartNumber' => $partNumber++,
        'ETag'       => $result['ETag'],
    );
}

// 3. Complete multipart upload.
$result = $s3->completeMultipartUpload(array(
    'Bucket'   => $bucket,
    'Key'      => $key,
    'UploadId' => $uploadId,
    'Parts'    => $parts,
));
$url = $result['Location'];

fclose($file);
```

Comment: I am trying this code to upload file of size 107MB. but file does not get upload on s3, when I check log on s3, it shows me for some parts of this file, "IncompleteBody". How do I deal with that??

Comment: This is what it shows in log : REST.PUT.PART 6/4/5_34fa2f47f8f2e3d/645_d48b407b9d44efc.mp4 "PUT /my.bucket/6/4/5_34fa2f47f8f2e3d/645_d48b407b9d44efc.mp4?partNumber=5&uploadId=C9utxlgdMqWCKrYuOEWyE2TOANRjx9r8YnDL3YV53kHVjEAGQ55U3IjqxodIAJRlbdQS8Fd5kWhHdlL_8kg-- HTTP/1.1" 400 IncompleteBody 260 5242880 3356 - "-" "aws-sdk-php2/2.8.20 Guzzle/3.9.3 curl/7.30.0 PHP/5.3.28"

I have also tried this solution " http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/usingHLmpuPHP.html" but its also giving same problem